# R and XML: 'flatten' XML tree with handlers?

Tags: xml, r

I'm using the `XML` package in R, and want to "flatten" an XML tree out to a string, using handlers in `xmlParse` to do various conversions (for example, convert `<code>...</code>` to `\code{...}` amongst others).

I am not entirely sure of the "proper" way to do this, and am seeking guidance.

I've thought of one way to do it in the example below, where I use a handler for the `code` tag to return the *string* `\code{contents}`, and the handler for the `p` tag to paste all the various bits together:

```
library(XML)
code.xml <- '<p>This is some <code>inline code</code>.</p>'
handlers <- list()
handlers$code <- function (node) {
    paste0('\\code{', xmlValue(node), '}')
}
# paste together the bits of text
handlers$p <- function(node) {
    bits <- sapply(xmlChildren(node), function (ch) {
        if (is.character(ch)) return(ch)
        xmlValue(ch)
    })
    paste(bits, collapse='')
}


xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(code.xml, asText=T, asTree=T,
                     handlers=handlers, trim=F,
                     useInternalNodes=F))

# "This is some \\code{inline code}."
```

However, this is not viable in that **for some elements I wish to have ancestry information** (like the parent node), and according to `xmlParse` this means I should use `useInternalNodes=TRUE` in my call to `xmlTreeParse`.

However, I also want to set `asTree=T` in my call to get my flattened strings back out of the call, but this gives an error:

```
xmlTreeParse(code.xml, asText=T, asTree=T,
             handlers=handlers, trim=F,
             useInternalNodes=T)

# Error in class(ans) = oldClass(class(ans)) :
#  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I am pretty sure this is because my handlers are returning strings rather than `XMLInternalNodes` so something's going wrong internally (?).

**What is another way I can flatten an XML tree into a string, applying user-defined transformations to particular tags (and I must be able to know what the parent node of the one I am transforming is)?**

(By the way, I am quite aware that my current method "wrong" way to do such a thing, but am not sure how I *should* be doing it. I feel that if I want to do various transformations like `<code></code>` to `\code{}` as I flatten my XML to a string, then I should be somehow using the XML parse tree (rather than regex, say), but this doesn't seem the right way. For one, the purpose of `xmlTreeParse` is not really to flatten and collect nodes!).